# JAVA Support for Semantic Web

Tags: java, web-services, semantic-web

Do java support semantic webservices.Any apis are available for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard Java APIs for semantic web; e.g. triple store access, querying, etc.  You basically have two alternatives for "doing semantic web stuff" in Java:

1. You can talk to an off-the-shelf SPARQL server using a standardized query language over HTTP.  The problem is that SPARQL doesn't provide a way to add, update or delete triples.
2. You code your application to use one of a number of (mostly incompatible) Java triple store APIs.  I use [Sesame](http://openrdf.org) and [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net) which are both open source, but there are a number of alternatives, including commercial offerings.

IMO, it is a *crying shame* that W3C or Sun has not come up with a standard Java API for creating, updating, deleting and querying RDF / triples.

Comment: Has W3C come up with _any_ Java APIs? I was unaware they were involved in API development.

Comment: I believe that the DOM APIs come from W3C.

Comment: W3C wrote the Dom APIs in IDL, in a language agnostic way. So you should have written: "has not come up with a standard API" instead... :-P

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KASWS](http://kasws.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Right now count of stable API for semantic web service is small.

Some API can be useful i think :

**- Apache Jena**

**[Apache Clerezza](http://incubator.apache.org/clerezza/)**

Some info about clerezza :

- OSGi-based Platform
- RESTful Web Service Framework
- JSR 223 compatible
- An API to access RDF Graph
- SPARQL Support

**[Apache Stanbol](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/)**

- has  RESTful interface
- LServices that add semantic information to “non-semantic” pieces of content.

  - **Another interesting opensource API is Linked Media Framework**

Comment: Semantic Web is not new, and there are *lots* of API's in many languages for the semantic web.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add [Apache Marmotta](http://marmotta.apache.org) to the list, a spin-out project from [Linked media Framework](http://lmf.googlecode.com).